# How to avoid warnings and errors in console of Chromedriver - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, console, selenium-chromedriver, warnings

I was using Chromedriver in order that Selenium Webdriver can control Chrome. Specifically, i use the following code

```
From Selenium import webdriver
import os

wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
wd.get("file://path.html"))
```

with this code, i manage to open the interested HTML file that i desire, however, that page tries to fetch certain elements, which are local and not in the interested html. As a consequence, opening the console of the page, i have errors and warnings related to the fact that it is trying to fetch local data
[This is the page that generates the errors and warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b1Gl.png)

The question is: how can i disallow or suppress these kinds of mistakes? By looking at other questions on Stackoverflow, i tried the following code but it seems is not doing the right job:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=OFF")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') 

wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe", options = chrome_options)
wd.get("file://path.html"))
```

Comment: You have one too many ")" after wd.get. In terms of errors you have done the right thing with setting the browser options, the only possible concern from that is the possibility that you didn't properly import the Options() object. The errors in your browser are most likely coming from the file itself that you're visiting, if it is trying to import resources. As you can see with the error file. What kinds of errors do you get when you just open the file in your browser without using selenium?

Comment: Regarding the ")", it is a mistake of pasting the code, so I'm aware but it is not the big issue here. The main issue is the warnings and errors in the console side (there is the link in which there is the screenshot). the kind of error is: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. I guess it is trying to fetch local data, but I'm not interested. For now, I used the method add_argument("--disable-web-security") which takes out 10 errors, but still 91 errors are left

Comment: Are you requiring any data or other modules from your selenium code because if not the errors are likely coming from the file itself.  Double check as well that you have the right link to the file because it can throw net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND if you don't use a relative file path.